# how to take as parameter json list to rest web api service

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have to take json list as parameter for web api.

```
http://localhost:8082/api/Values/EmptyCardList?number=[
{
    num: "1"
},
{
    num: "2"
},
{
    num: "3"
},
{
    num: "4"
},
{
    num: "5"
},
{
    num: "6"
},
{
    num: "7"
}
]
```

Is it possible ? Can it lead performance problem? Also parameter how much take character or list ?

Comment: Is your request HttpPost?

Comment: yes.because I want to sent parameter json dataset in my service.After my service take this request and insert all data in my database.you can think as bulk insert.Is it possible ? or do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: @SerdarToprak refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619302/restful-urls-with-data-in-query-string-or-request-body if you using Restful URLs with data in query string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are making your httpPost request and passing json object in your request body

Set

```
contentType:"application/json"
```

and in data use `JSON.stringify(yourJson);`

Something like this:

```
    $(function () {
    var youJsondata = {num :"2",num:"3"};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data :JSON.stringify(youJsondata),
        url: "http://localhost:8082/api/Values/emptycardlist",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
});
```

You api method should look something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
Route("api/Values/emptycardlist")
public HttpResponseMessage EmptyCardList([FromBody] JObject jobject){
   dynamic numList = jobject;
}
```

[Reference](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing)