# url put request OkHTTPClient

Tags: java, request

I am trying to achieve this

[image]

Which is `/delete/{id}`

How do I do this in java?

```
String id = "123";
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody form = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("id", id)
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
           .url("http://localhost:3002/delete/")
           .put(form)
           .build();
        client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Doesn't work. How do I add url parameters with this?

Comment: which library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the `id` to the `url` function argument like `url("http://localhost:3002/delete/"+id)`. You have a request query parameter and you are not appending it to the URL.
Also, `put(form)` sets the request body and not the query parameter.

You can check out the difference between [PUT and POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)  and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619302/restful-urls-with-data-in-query-string-or-request-body) for more explanation